# Showing Different fields in EditorForModel vs. DisplayForModel modes in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorformodel

I have a viewmodel that has an `int StateID` field and a `string StateName` field like so:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel : BaseViewModel, IModelWithId
{
    // only show in edit mode
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    // only show in display mode
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a read only view that uses `DisplayForModel` and an update view that uses `EditorForModel`. I want the `DisplayForModel` view to show the `StateName` property, and the `EditorForModel` view use the `StateID` property (I am actually rendering a dropdownlist based on this).

I have not been able to figure out how to decorate my viewmodel properties to create this behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wanted a solution that was more generic, so I created a new attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class RenderModeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public RenderMode RenderMode { get; set; }

    public RenderModeAttribute(RenderMode renderMode)
    {
        RenderMode = renderMode;
    }
}

public enum RenderMode
{
    Any,
    EditModeOnly,
    DisplayModeOnly
}
```

And included the following code in my custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider:

```
var renderModeAttribute = attributes.OfType<RenderModeAttribute>();
if (renderModeAttribute.Any())
{
    var renderMode = renderModeAttribute.First().RenderMode;
    switch (renderMode)
    {
        case RenderMode.DisplayModeOnly:
            metadata.ShowForDisplay = true;
            metadata.ShowForEdit = false;
            break;
        case RenderMode.EditModeOnly:
            metadata.ShowForDisplay = false;
            metadata.ShowForEdit = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

So that I could just decorate my model as so:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel    
{     
    [RenderMode(RenderMode.EditModeOnly)]   
    public int StateId { get; set; }     

    [RenderMode(RenderMode.DisplayModeOnly)]    
    public string StateName { get; set; }     
}
```

Comment: How do you implement the custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider? Thanks.

Comment: @UpTheCreek - Inherit from DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider. http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2010/06/11/custom-asp-net-mvc-2-modelmetadataprovider-for-using-custom-view-model-attributes.aspx

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. It would be useful though if you could give details of where the second code snippet needs to go (I assume we need to override CreateMetadata and put it in there?) and also how to register our custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider once created.

Answer (score 17):

A comment on CodeGrue's answer.

Make the attribute inherit IMetadataAware instead. That way you don't need to build your own DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.

The new attribute would become something like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class RenderModeAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public RenderMode RenderMode { get; set; }

    public RenderModeAttribute(RenderMode renderMode)
    {
        RenderMode = renderMode;
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        switch (RenderMode)
        {
            case RenderMode.DisplayModeOnly:
                metadata.ShowForDisplay = true;
                metadata.ShowForEdit = false;
                break;

            case RenderMode.EditModeOnly:
                metadata.ShowForDisplay = false;
                metadata.ShowForEdit = true;
                break;

            case RenderMode.None:
                metadata.ShowForDisplay = false;
                metadata.ShowForEdit = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum RenderMode
{
    Any,
    EditModeOnly,
    DisplayModeOnly
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my custom provider, I add a None render mode

```
public class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Attribute> attributes, System.Type containerType, System.Func<object> modelAccessor, System.Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        var renderModeAttribute = attributes.OfType<RenderModeAttribute>();
        if (renderModeAttribute.Any())
        {
            var renderMode = renderModeAttribute.First().RenderMode;
            switch (renderMode)
            {
                case RenderMode.DisplayModeOnly:
                    metadata.ShowForDisplay = true;
                    metadata.ShowForEdit = false;
                    break;

                case RenderMode.EditModeOnly:
                    metadata.ShowForDisplay = false;
                    metadata.ShowForEdit = true;
                    break;

                case RenderMode.None:
                    metadata.ShowForDisplay = false;
                    metadata.ShowForEdit = false;
                    break;
            }
        } 

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the templates:

In `~/Shared/EditorTemplates/DepartmentViewModel.ascx` put:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Namespace.DepartmentViewModel>" %>
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.StateId) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StateId) %>
```

And in your `~/Shared/DisplayTemplates/DepartmentViewModel.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Namespace.DepartmentViewModel>" %>
<div><%= Html.Encode(Model.StateName) %></div>
```